# NSColor show different color in the screen

Tags: macos, cocoa

I extend NSColor to add class method

```
+ (NSColor*) initWithHTMLString: (NSString*) rgb
```

I set the background color for a NSWindow object:

```
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor initWithHTMLString:@"37854F"]]
NSLog(@"Color=%@",[self.window.backgroundColor toHTMLRGB]);
```

When I run the program, the log line is `"Color=37854F"`. However, I use the tool PixelStick to drop the color pixel, the pixel color is not `37854F`, the color component is little smaller than its origin.

Are there any people know the solution?

Comment: What is `toHTMLRGB`? What is the code for your `initWithHTMLString:`? What color does PixelStick say it is?

Comment: In addition, consider "device" versus "calibrated" color spaces (See Color Programming Topics" guide in documentation).

Comment: @matt toHTMLRGB formrat NSColor to NSString, initWithHTMLString: just cut off two bytes and change to unsigned int, using colorWithCalibratedRed:green:blue:alpha: to create new NSColor object.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi Your comment shaded me a light. I will read more about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that colors created with obj-c are adjusted to take the current color profile into account (see system preferences -> Monitors -> Colors). This goes so far that the same color appears differently when you have several monitors and drag your running application from one monitor to the other. Unfortunately, it's extremely difficult to use an exact color on a particular monitor, even if you use colorWithDeviceRed:Green:Blue:Alpha instead colorWithCalibratedRed:Green:Blue:Alpha.

Color perception is a complex matter and various output devices play an important role, so no wonder there is no 1:1 mapping. But it should really be possible to create a color (say in a painting app or color management app, designer app etc.) and recreate the exact same color in Cocoa, if both run on the same monitor.

Interesting to note is here: when you have your colors in a design on OSX (be it an image in a browser or PDF file or whatever) and use its component values in a Windows app in a virtual machine (e.g. in Parallels Desktop) you can reproduce the exact color as any screen color picker shows.

[Update]: Since setting the system color profile to a generic one solves the color matching it might be worth thinking about creating an own generic color space in code as described in this [technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1396/_index.html)

[Update]: I just found another NSColor message that looks like is what we both are looking for:

```
NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:green:blue:alpha
```

In a few tests I could see the color was exact. Unfortunately this message is only available on 10.7 and higher.

Comment: Your information is useful but it is not my case. My case is in the same monitor. I use HTML RGB string it is picked from Java program and put in my Mac OS X program. When I run two application (Java+Mac) in same monitor, they are different.

Comment: That's what I say. Read again. You are creating the color in Obj-C code and when it's displayed on the screen it is not the same color as that from the java program where you got the component values from.

Comment: How do we make NSColor independent with current display profile?

Comment: I thought colorWithDeviceRed:Green:Blue:Alpha would do that job, but the colors never match exactly. So I don't know. That's why I wrote about the problems in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your information. If I select generic RGB profile. The color is same. But the user can select the another profile. How do we can know which profile is selected now?

Comment: I added a link that might be useful for you to my answer.

Comment: NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:green:blue:alpha can be replaced by NSColor colorWithColorSpace: components: count:. However, it isnot the solution. technical Q&A can be a solution, but the functions are now depreciated take example CMGetSystemProfile.

Comment: Thanks you for your support. From your information, I can manage to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is how you init an NSColor with an exact screen color (Swift 3):

```
let components = [red, green, blue, alpha]

let color = NSColor(
    colorSpace: NSScreen.main()!.colorSpace!, 
    components: components,
    count: 4)
```

If you color-pick a screenshot you can confirm that the RGB components match exactly.